# Сокращение объема кода по работе с табами (скрытие/отображение)

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Есть табы, которые скрыты, при клике по элементу с нужным атрибутом, таб появляется. Как такой код, можно сократить? Причём, чем короче получится, тем лучше.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".style_of_tabs").hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.tab_add', function (){
var post = {};
post.ajaxRequest = true;
$metod = $(this).data('metod');
if($metod == 'country'){
    $('#country').show();
    post.country = true;
}
if($metod == 'currenci'){
    $('#currenci').show();
    post.currenci = true;
}
if($metod == 'package'){
    $('#package').show();
    post.package = true;
}
if($metod == 'activitidirection'){
    $('#activitidirection').show();
    post.activitidirection = true;
}
if($metod == 'branch'){
    $('#branch').show();
    post.branch = true;
}
if($metod == 'industrialdirection'){
    $('#industrialdirection').show();
    post.industrialdirection = true;
}
if($metod == 'measuri'){
    $('#measuri').show();
    post.measuri = true;
}
if($metod == 'fo'){
    $('#fo').show();
    post.fo = true;
}
if($metod == 'region'){
    $('#region').show();
    post.region = true;
}
if($metod == 'logistic'){
    $('#logistic').show();
    post.logistic = true;
}
if($metod == 'quality'){
    $('#quality').show();
    post.quality = true;
}
$(this).hide();
console.log(post);
var result = sendAjaxRequest({
  url: '/infobase/getTabs',
  data: post
});
```

});

Comment: Если в if'ах перечислены все возможные значения `$metod`, то их можно заменить чем-то таким: `$('#' + $metod).show(); post[$metod] = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".style_of_tabs").hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.tab_add', function (){
  var post = {
    ajaxRequest: true
  };

  var $method = $(this).data('method');

  // >>> доступные методы
  var methods = ['country', 'currenci', 'package', 'activitidirection', 'branc', 'industrialdirection', 'measuri'];

  // >>> проверка, что метод в списке доступных
  if (methods.indexOf($method) < 0) {
     console.warn('method not allowed');
     return;
  }

  // только в том случае, если имена совпадают
  $('#' + $method).show();
  post[$method] = true;

  $(this).hide();

  console.log(post);

  var result = sendAjaxRequest({
    url: '/infobase/getTabs',
    data: post
  });
});
```